# Does moving between pages end a Socket.io connection in Flask?

Tags: javascript, python, flask, socket.io, flask-socketio

This is a conceptual problem I'm not quite understanding when it comes to Websockets.

I'm trying to make a game in python using Flask, Flask-socket.io and jQuery.
I'm using 'Rooms' to store the id of the game, so players can connect to the same game using a specific id.

Once the game has started, do I need stay on the same html page and just change the content using jQuery, or can I move to a new html page (flask route) and access the 'Room' data there?

Thanks.

Comment: When you leave the current site, the connection will be closed. If you navigate to another page, the client will be (re)connected and can join the room again.

Comment: So will the client rejoin the room they were in automatically or would they have to pass the name of that room again to the server somehow?

Comment: You need to manually rejoin the room.

Comment: Or load the pages in an iframe like I do. Just grab the parents document socket connection.